# ngfor object angular2 (final release)

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a list of objects, each object's like :

```
object : {
  attr1 : string,
  attr2 : string,
  object1 : {
    attr3 : string,
    attr4 : string
  }
}
```

In my `HTML` file :

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of objects">
  <td>{{object.attr1}}</td>
</tr>
```

That works fine. I'd like to access to `attr3`.

```
<td>{{object.object1.attr3}}</td>
```

I tried this but it's not working

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean exactly? Does **every object** actually have the `attr3` attribute or only some?

Comment: in case of object1 is null or undefined, it throws an exception

Comment: What exception?

Comment: .... caused by: Cannot read property 'object1' of null

Comment: solution : <td>{{object.object1?.attr3}}</td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess

```
<td>{{object.object1?.attr3}}</td>
```